# Master-Detail-Detail View for Mobile

Tags: mobile, data-tables, master-details

I'm designing a mobile app that uses a master-detail-detail model. The first screen is a list of records from table A. The user can select on record and show the details of that record. Then there is a list of sub records from table B where the user can also select one record to have a look at the details.

Now for a web application the user interface isn't too difficult, but I'm not sure whether the design on the very limited space of a mobile phone is suitable. There are two navigation bars at the same time. One for level 1 (Table A) and one for level 2 (Table B).

Is this a good design or how could this be improved?

Here's a sketch:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Look good for me if table B is related/child of each Table A item.**

BUT to confirm it, make a prototype. You can easily do it on an Adobe XD or any other UX software. You should create some cases/scripts (How many cases? Enough to simulate all user situations) and then simulate the navigation on the wireframe prototype to feel as your user. And please as soon as you are happy with your tests, also put some real user to test the prototype, give some goals, watch they navigating and in the end make a fast interview to understand the actions and doubts about the app.